# UIToolbar doesn't show up after it's being hidden

Tags: objective-c, uitoolbar

I got a UIButton which makes the UIToolbar show and hide.

```
- (IBAction)showHideToolbar:(id)sender{
    if (toolBar.hidden == NO) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^(void){toolBar.alpha =0.0f;}completion:^(BOOL finished){
            toolBar.hidden = YES;}];
        NSLog(@"hides");
    }
    else
        if (toolBar.hidden == YES) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^(void){toolBar.alpha =0.0f;}completion:^(BOOL finished){
                toolBar.hidden = NO;
            }];
            NSLog(@"show");
        }
}
```

The problem is that when i try to hide the toolBar,it works fine. But when i try to show it again, it won't show up.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you animate the showing of the toolbar you have to set the alpha to `1.0f` in the `animations` block.

Below is the correct code; I've marked the line that I changed with a comment.

```
- (IBAction)showHideToolbar:(id)sender {
    if (toolBar.hidden == NO) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f 
                              delay:0.0f 
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                         animations:^(void){ toolBar.alpha = 0.0f; }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ toolBar.hidden = YES; }];
        NSLog(@"hides");
}
else
    if (toolBar.hidden == YES) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f 
                              delay:0.0f
                            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction 
                         animations:^(void){ toolBar.alpha = 1.0f; } // Change from 0.0f to 1.0f
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){ toolBar.hidden = NO; }];
        NSLog(@"show");
    }
}
```